# Order of a matrix over a field extension

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I was solving [this puzzle problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/feistelfun) which amounts to the following: what is the order of the matrix
$$T = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & z\end{bmatrix}$$
over $F_2[z]$, where $z$ is an $m$-th root of unity?

My reasoning was as follows: the characteristic polynomial of $T$, over $F_2[z]$, is the quadratic $x(x-z)-1= x^2 -xz - 1 = 0$. The characteristic polynomial over $F_2$ therefore divides $g(x) = f(xz) - f(x^2-1)$, where $f$ is the $m$-th cyclotomic polynomial. $g(x)$ has degree $2\phi(m)$; since polynomials in $F_p$ of degree $d$ have polynomial order dividing $p^d-1$, $g$ has polynomial order dividing $2^{2\phi(m)} - 1$ and therefore the order of $T$ must divide $2^{2\phi(m)} - 1$.

However, this is false, even for $m=2$, although from some numerical examples it appears that the order of $T$ does divide $\operatorname{lcm}(m, 2^{2\phi(m)}-1)$. What's the flaw in the above reasoning and what's the correct argument?

Comment: What goes wrong when $m=2$? Surely $T$ has order three then. Anyway, $z$ is an element of the field $\Bbb{F}_{2^\ell}$, $\ell\mid\phi(m)$. Therefore the eigenvalues of $T$ are in the field $\Bbb{F}_{2^{2\ell}}$. The eigenvalues are distinct, and your claim follows.

Comment: Hmm. Because we are in characteristic two, $m$ is always odd, and $m=2$ is equivalent to $m=1$. As long as we interpret $\phi(1)=1$, we are ok.

Comment: Was the flaw due to the fact that $g\notin F_2[x]$?